# Shift groupby by an unknown number of line

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a pivot table coming from a dataframe with the same structure as below:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame([[123456,datetime(2020,7,1), "XXX",'A',1 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1), "XXX",'B',2 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1), "XXX",'C',3 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1), "YYY",'A',4 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1), "YYY",'B',5 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1), "YYY",'C',6 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2), "XXX",'A',7 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2), "XXX",'B',8 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2), "XXX",'C',float('NaN'),
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2), "YYY",'A',9 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2), "YYY",'B',10 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2), "YYY",'C',11 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,1), "XXX",'A',12 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,1), "XXX",'B',13 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,1), "XXX",'C',14 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,2), "XXX",'A',15 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,2), "XXX",'B',16 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,2), "XXX",'C',17 ],
                           ] , columns=['GROUP_ID','DATE', 'REFERENCE', 'NAME', 'VALUE'])

pt = raw.pivot_table(index=['GROUP_ID', 'DATE', 'REFERENCE'], columns=['NAME'], values=['VALUE'])

                              VALUE
                    NAME      A    B    C
GROUP_ID      DATE  REFERENCE           
123456  2020-07-01  XXX       1.0  2.0  3.0
                    YYY       4.0  5.0  6.0
        2020-07-02  XXX       7.0  8.0  NaN
                    YYY       9.0 10.0 11.0
789012  2020-07-01  XXX      12.0 13.0 14.0
        2020-07-02  XXX      15.0 16.0 17.0
```

The idea is to create a column `("VALUE_PREV", "C")` where i can have the value of the previous date inside each `GROUP_ID`.
If i do `pt[("VALUE_PREV","C")] = pt["VALUE"].groupby(level=0)["C"].shift()` i have :

```
                                VALUE          VALUE_PREV
                         NAME   A    B    C      C
GROUP_ID      DATE  REFERENCE               
123456  2020-07-01  XXX        1.0   2.0   3.0  NaN
                    YYY        4.0   5.0   6.0  3.0
        2020-07-02  XXX        7.0   8.0   NaN  6.0
                    YYY        9.0  10.0  11.0  NaN
789012  2020-07-01  XXX       12.0  13.0  14.0  NaN
        2020-07-02  XXX       15.0  16.0  17.0 14.0
```

So here on the last line in the `VALUE_PREV`column `14.0` is well placed but `3.0` and `6.0` should be one line below. The solution could be to do `shift(2)` but the number of `REFERENCE` by date varies depending on the `GROUP_ID` and then `14.0` would be one line below.
So i don't know how to get that number of `REFERENCE` per `GROUP_ID` to adjust the `shift()` dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to solve for this by doing this ahead of time in the `raw` DataFrame.

First we need to create the offset of exactly a day based on your criteria, for this we will need a `tseries`.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
offset = DateOffset(days=1)
```

Then we will need to create the shifted values.

```
shifted = raw.reset_index().set_index("DATE").shift(1, freq=offset).reset_index().drop(columns="index")
```

Then we can join the two datasets together.

```
df = raw.merge(shifted, how="left", on=["GROUP_ID", "DATE", "REFERENCE", "NAME"], suffixes=["CURRENT", "PREV"])
```

Lastly we call the pivot function you had previously.

```
df.pivot_table(index=["GROUP_ID", "DATE", "REFERENCE"], columns="NAME", values=["VALUECURRENT", "VALUEPREV"])

                              VALUECURRENT             VALUEPREV            
NAME                                     A     B     C         A     B     C
GROUP_ID DATE       REFERENCE                                               
123456   2020-07-01 XXX                1.0   2.0   3.0       NaN   NaN   NaN
                    YYY                4.0   5.0   6.0       NaN   NaN   NaN
         2020-07-02 XXX                7.0   8.0   NaN       1.0   2.0   3.0
                    YYY                9.0  10.0  11.0       4.0   5.0   6.0
789012   2020-07-01 XXX               12.0  13.0  14.0       NaN   NaN   NaN
         2020-07-02 XXX               15.0  16.0  17.0      12.0  13.0  14.0
```

Comment: Thanks it works, just to be sure, i get the same results with `raw.set_index("DATE").shift(1, freq=offset).reset_index()` instead of `raw.reset_index().set_index("DATE").shift(1, freq=offset).reset_index().drop(columns="index")` for `shifted`, did i miss something and it's useful at some point ?

Comment: nope, either way is fine, one way is just more verbose than the other